# other packages also run on my android app

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have to run my android application which means am getting the following messages on my logcat window:

```
  12:05:36.056:  System_process  I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.xmlparsing/.MainActivity: 581 ms (total 581 ms)
  12:05:41.136:  com.android.defcon   D/dalvikvm(253): GC_EXPLICIT freed 152 objects / 11024 bytes in 60ms
  12:05:46.126:  com.svox.pico   D/dalvikvm(264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31 objects / 1512 bytes in 50ms
  12:05:51.156:  com.android.setting D/dalvikvm(125): GC_EXPLICIT freed 975 objects / 42392 bytes in 78ms
   12:06:40.666:  com.xmlparsing D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3884 objects / 321368 bytes in 50ms
  12:06:40.836: com.xmlparsing   D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3654 objects / 427296 bytes in 48ms
  12:06:41.026: com.xmlparsing D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4007 objects / 418288 bytes in 45ms
  12:06:41.245: com.xmlparsing D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4516 objects / 414608 bytes in 54ms
  12:06:41.456: com.xmlparsing  D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4194 objects / 399504 bytes in 53ms
  12:06:41.616: com.xmlparsing D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3365 objects / 412104 bytes in 43ms
  12:06:41.666: com.xmlparsing I/System.out(1131): category size6
   12:06:41.666: com.xmlparsing I/System.out(1131): category name is---------------->Photos
```

Here my application package is com.xmlparsing.

But here other packages(com.android.defcon,com.svox.pico,com.android.settings) is running on starting.this packages only taking more time to reading(loading) the data.please check the time.my xml file is read within second.why that package is loading.how can i control it.please give me solution for these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages are not running "on your app". Android supports multitasking, so it is possible to have more than one app alive at a time.

In any case, the LogCat you posted shows that it is simply a GC call, which means Android is trying to free up memory. There is nothing you can do to control this.

If you want to view LogCay messages from only your app, try filtering by process id.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing are log messages from the different processes that are going through Garbage Collection (GC).

On any system, Android or otherwise, there will likely be multiple processes running at the same time.  On Android, the processes will periodically go through Garbage Collection to free up memory and keep the system running well and within its constrained resources.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: am fetching data from xml feed is fast.within one second i have fetched data.but the app is loading very slow on starting stage.how can i reduce these loading time.please provide me solution for these.

Comment: You'd need to post some source code for us to tell you why it's running slowly.  It's likely outside of the scope of this question.